# How to create a true-for-all index on a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, filter

I am using pandas and have run into a few occasions where I have a programmatically generated list of conditionals, like so

```
conditionals = [
    df['someColumn'] == 'someValue',
    df['someOtherCol'] == 'someOtherValue',
    df['someThirdCol'].isin(['foo','bar','baz']),
   ]
```

and I want to select rows where ALL of these conditions are true. I figure I'd do something like this.

```
bigConditional = IHaveNoIdeaOfWhatToPutHere

for conditional in conditionals:
   bigConditional = bigConditional && conditional
filteredDf = df[bigConditional]
```

I know that I WANT to use the identity property, to where bigConditional is initialized to a series of true for every index in my dataframe, such that if any condition in my conditionals list evaluates to false that row won't be in the filtered dataframe, but initially every row is considered.

I don't know how to do that, or at least not the best most succinct way that shows it's intentional

Also, I've run into inverse scenarios where I only need on of the conditionals to match to include the row into the new dataframe, so I would need bigConditional to be set to false for every index in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about sum the conditions and check if it is equal to the number of conditions

```
filteredDf = df.loc[sum(conditionals)==len(conditionals)]
```

or even more simple, with `np.all`

```
filteredDf = df.loc[np.all(conditionals, axis=0)]
```

otherwise, for your original question, you can create a series of True indexed like df and your `for` loop should work.

```
bigConditional = pd.Series(True, index=df.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `query` and generate your conditions like this:

```
conditionals = [
    "someColumn == 'someValue'",
    "someOtherCol == 'someOtherValue'",
    "someThirdCol.isin(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])",
]

qs = ' & '.join(conditionals)

out = df.query(qs)
```

Or use `eval` to create boolean values instead of filter your dataframe:

```
mask = df.eval(qs)
```

**Demo**

Suppose this dataframe:

```
>>> df
     someColumn    someOtherCol  someThirdCol
0     someValue  someOtherValue           foo
1     someValue  someOtherValue           baz
2     someValue    anotherValue  anotherValue
3  anotherValue    anotherValue  anotherValue

>>> df.query(qs)
  someColumn    someOtherCol someThirdCol
0  someValue  someOtherValue          foo
1  someValue  someOtherValue          baz

>>> df.eval(qs)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

You can even use f-strings or another template language to pass variables to your condition list.